# Filter rows according to array in another tab

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the follow filter

```
=FILTER(A2:A,MATCH(A2:A,'sheet 1'!A2:A,0))
```

Within a custom formula but it's not responding.
If I use

```
=FILTER(A2:A,MATCH(A2:A,I2:I,0))
```

It works fine.

[Here is a link to a test sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DlLa3_LPYUJWvagqA9T1x3qMJJA7Ek2CVSisljvEPVY/edit?usp=sharing)
When I add or remove letters to the first sheet the column under the Letters in the second sheet just bellow the orange respond accordingly. I cannot get the filter view to work with the same formula.

Comment: Share your sheet if possible, at first glance there is nothing wrong with your formula.

Comment: Added link to the original post

Comment: Wait, so the problem is with the filter _view_ and not the formula?

Comment: It seems that you cannot reference other ranges than the range being filtered in the filter formula. I tried to put =match(A2:A, {"a", "b", "d"}, 0) as your custom filter formula, and it works. But when I transform it to =match(A2:A, H11:H15, 0) it stops working. Seems like an undocumented limitation of Google Sheets (one of many...)

Comment: Actually I found a way to do it using indirect... watch for my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following for your filter view formula:

```
=match(A2:A, indirect("Sheet1!a1:a5"), 0)
```

Alas, it works only at the moment of applying the filter for the 1st time. Changing the values in Sheet1!a1:a5 will not automatically cause the filter to refresh. The only way to do that is via a =FILTER() formula, not via the UI filter view.

Answer (score 0):

Check your name of the sheet being referenced. Unless you changed the name it should be `Sheet1!A2:A`.

Comment: Not the issue. the name is actually unique, just wanted to make the example generic.

Comment: It works for me regardless of sheet reference. Is the formula part of another, more complex, formula or perhaps trying to pull info from a completely separate Spreadsheet?